# Capturing signal from different widgets

Tags: python, pyqt

I apologized in advance if my title is off. I have a bunch of widgets in my tool and I am trying to make the signals run an extra method if User made changes onto them, primarily the QLineEdits and QSliders.

As I have created them using the Qt Designer, their signals are set in the `main.py`, and the methods for the sliders/ line edits are pretty much the same:

```py
class MyUI(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, dockable=True):
        super(MyUI, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        # calling from my converted .ui file
        self.ui = Ui_MyTool()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self._connect_signals()

    def _connect_signals(self):
        self.ui.posXSlider.valueChanged.connect(self.pos_x_slider)
        self.ui.posYSlider.valueChanged.connect(self.pos_y_slider)
        self.ui.posZSlider.valueChanged.connect(self.pos_z_slider)
        self.ui.transparencySlider.valueChanged.connect(self.transparency_slider)

        self.ui.posXLineEdit.editingFinished.connect(self.pos_x_edit)
        self.ui.posYLineEdit.editingFinished.connect(self.pos_y_edit)
        self.ui.posZLineEdit.editingFinished.connect(self.pos_z_edit)
        self.ui.transparencyLineEdit.editingFinished.connect(self.transparency_edit)

    def pos_x_slider(self, value):
        value /= 100.0
        self.posXLineEdit.setText(str(value))

        self.run_this_extra_method()

    def pos_x_edit(self):
        value = float(self.ui.posXLineEdit.text())
        self.ui.posXSlider.setValue(float(value) * 100.0)

        self.run_this_extra_method()

    def run_this_extra_method(self):
        # doing some other stuff
```

As you can see that I am calling `run_this_extra_method` in both the slider and line edit methods, and seeing that I have 4 sliders + 4 line edits, that would makes 8 calls/ lines of `run_this_extra_method`.

Are there ways in which I can 'collate'/'capture' or some sort, such that I can call `run_this_extra_method` once whenever User makes any changes towards one of these widgets?

Comment: Please publish the module containing the class `Ui_MyTool`

Comment: Create a flag that denotes that you have run the function already and that gets reset to not having been run for the criterion reasons you set forth for instance `if not self.ExtraMethodRun: self.run_this_extra_method;  self.ExtraMethodRun = True`

Comment: @S.Nick Here is the [ui module](https://pastebin.com/qnhwUsxd)

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

**main.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

from uiMyTool import Ui_MyTool

class MyUI(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, dockable=True):
        super(MyUI, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        # calling from my converted .ui file
        self.ui = Ui_MyTool()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self._connect_signals()

        self.flag_of_extra_method = False                                          # +++

    def _connect_signals(self):
        self.ui.positionXHorizontalSlider.valueChanged.connect(self.pos_x_slider)
        self.ui.positionXLineEdit.editingFinished.connect(self.pos_x_edit)

    def pos_x_slider(self, value):
        value /= 100.0
        self.ui.positionXLineEdit.setText(str(value))

        if not self.flag_of_extra_method:                                         # +++
            self.run_this_extra_method()                                          # +++
        self.flag_of_extra_method = not self.flag_of_extra_method                 # +++

    def pos_x_edit(self):
        value = float(self.ui.positionXLineEdit.text())
        self.ui.positionXHorizontalSlider.setValue(float(value) * 100.0)

        if not self.flag_of_extra_method:                                         # +++
            self.run_this_extra_method()                                          # +++
        self.flag_of_extra_method = not self.flag_of_extra_method                 # +++    


    def run_this_extra_method(self):
        if not self.flag_of_extra_method:                                         # +++
            # doing some other stuff
            print("run_this_extra_method")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyUI()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]